# Emulating %defstr in earlier versions of NASM

Tags: nasm

Is there a way to emulate `%defstr` in NASM versions earlier than 2.03, preferably 0.99.06? More particularly, I want this macro to work:

```
%macro name 1
%defstr __namestr__ %1
%1: db __namestr__, 0
%endmacro
```

so that `name hello` would be equivalent to `hello: db 'hello', 0`. It already works in NASM 2.03 and later. I need it in a portable NASM include file, and requiring the user to upgrade NASM is not an option.

This doesn't work, it emits a literal `%1` (2 bytes) + NUL.

```
%macro name 1
%1: db '%1', 0
%endif
```

NASM 0.99.06 .. NASM 2.02 documentation says that *a workaround can be created using a multi-line macro* (for converting tokens to a string literal), but it doesn't specify how. The full excerpt:

```
   The `%!<env>' directive makes it possible to read the value of an
   environment variable at assembly time. This could, for example, be
   used to store the contents of an environment variable into a string,
   which could be used at some other point in your code.

   For example, suppose that you have an environment variable `FOO',
   and you want the contents of `FOO' to be embedded in your program.
   You could do that as follows:

   %define FOO    %!FOO 
   %define quote   ' 

   tmpstr  db      quote FOO quote

   At the time of writing, this will generate an "unterminated string"
   warning at the time of defining "quote", and it will add a space
   before and after the string that is read in. I was unable to find a
   simple workaround (although a workaround can be created using a
   multi-line macro), so I believe that you will need to either learn
   how to create more complex macros, or allow for the extra spaces if
   you make use of this feature in that way.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set of possible namestr values is small, then they can be predefined:

```
%define NAME_foo 'foo'
%define NAME_bar 'bar'
%define NAME_foobar 'foobar'

%macro name 1
%1: db NAME_%1, 0
%endmacro
```

Answer (score 2):

- The preprocessor macro `%defstr` is “smart” enough and [*escapes*](https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/blob/nasm-2.15.xx/asm/quote.c#L44-L188), for instance, any occurrence of string delimiter characters.
  Therefore it’s different from a `%define` simply surrounding the argument with quotes.
- However, in your specific case, since the first and only parameter to the `name` macro *must also be suitable label*, you do not have to worry about problematic characters.
  Taking the excerpt from the documentation as inspiration and after having verified that `%+` was already documented in `0.98.x`, you can write something like:

  ```
  %define quote '

  %macro name 1
    %1: db quote %+%1%+ quote, 0
  %endmacro
  ```

  I did only check this with NASM version 2.15.05, so no guarantee that this indeed works with 0.99.06.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This indeed works with NASM 2.15.05. However, in NASM 0.98.39 and NASM 0.99.06, it doesn't generate the expected binary output (which mustn't contain `%+`), so I can't accept the answer.

Comment: Also this makes NASM (all 3 versions) display a warning about an unterminated string.

Comment: It’s a pity. Another attempt was `%[quote]%1%[quote]` but macro indirection (the `%[…]` syntax) became available in 2.08. The _unterminated string_ warning was already documented in the old documentation. It is “correct”. Have you considered using already embedded `strings(1)`?